# Set class of row using Ajax Pager

Tags: tablesorter

I'm using the ajax pager plugin and I want to know if it's possible to add a class to a row based on a value in the returned JSON data. For example, turn a row red if a cell has a certain value.

```
ajaxProcessing: function(data){
  if (data && data.hasOwnProperty('rows')) { 
    var r, row, c, d = data.rows, 
    total = data.total_rows, 
    headers = data.headers, 
    rows = [], 
    len = d.length; 
    for ( r=0; r < len; r++ ) { 
      row = [];
      for ( c in d[r] ) { 
        if (typeof(c) === "string") { 
          row.push(d[r][c]); 
        } 
      } 
      // is there a way to do that here when it pushes the row onto the array
      // or perhaps there is another function you have implemented that will let me do that
      rows.push(row);
    } 
    return [ total, rows, headers ]; 
  } 
},
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

[`ajaxProcessing`](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#pager-ajaxprocessing) is a callback function that allows you to return the data shown in the question, or just the total number of rows ([ref](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#array_total_only)):

```
ajaxProcessing: function(data, table, xhr){
  if (data && data.hasOwnProperty('rows')) {
    var r, row, c, d = data.rows,
    // total number of rows (required)
    total = data.total_rows,
    // all rows: array of arrays; each internal array has the table cell data for that row
    rows = '',
    // len should match pager set size (c.size)
    len = d.length;
    // this will depend on how the json is set up - see City0.json
    // rows
    for ( r=0; r < len; r++ ) {
      rows += '<tr class="ajax-row">'; // new row
      // cells
      for ( c in d[r] ) {
        if (typeof(c) === "string") {
          rows += '<td>' + d[r][c] + '</td>'; // add each table cell data to row
        }
      }
      rows += '</tr>'; // end new row
    }
    // find first sortable tbody, then add new rows
    table.config.$tbodies.eq(0).html(rows);
    // no need to trigger an update method, it's done internally
    return [ total ];
  }
}
```

before `return [ total ];`, a method can be used to find the row and add the class name, if it isn't already done while building the string.

Alternatively, the call to the server can return HTML strings that already include the class name applied to the row ([ref](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#array_rows_as_jquery_object)):

```
ajaxProcessing: function(data, table, xhr){
  if (data && data.hasOwnProperty('rows')) {
    // data.rows would look something like this
    // '<tr class="fred"><td>r0c0</td><td>r0c1</td></tr><tr><td>r1c0</td><td>r1c1</td></tr>'
    return [ data.total, $(data.rows), data.headers ];
  }
}
```

Comment: That you so much Mottie! That last bit was exactly what I was looking for. I know that you mention in the docs that you can return all of the table rows, but I couldn't quite figure out how to do it. This works great. Thanks again.